# Net-SNMP: how to specify octet string in Hex bytes in SET command?

Tags: string, hex, byte, snmp, net-snmp

I use net-snmp-5.5-1.x86.exe for Win32

I need set IP addreess to hex format, separated by whitespace using NET-SNMP set command. For example, an IP address 192.168.100.100 converted to Hex format is 0xC0A86464

```
192.168.100.100 > 0xC0A86464
```

The correctly set value should return the following value when check with snmpget:

```
xxx-xxx-xxx-MIB::docsDevServerAddress.0 = Hex-STRING: C0 A8 64 64
```

I tried

```
snmpset -v 1 -c private 192.168.100.5 docsDevServerAddress.0 x 0xC0 A8 64 64
```

But when I using this format to set HEX address, I always got errors like this: `'A8: Bad object type: 6'`, or `'00xA8 Bad object type: 0'`, and so on, depending on representation of hex format I tried.
According to NET-SNMP manual, 'x' is octet string in hex bytes, separated by whitespace.

How to set correct string input format for snmpset to set Hex values I need?

Answer (score 3):

old question but maybe useful for others.

```
snmpset -v 1 -c private 192.168.100.5 docsDevServerAddress.0 x "C0 A8 64 64"
```

Comment: simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove extra spaces inside your hex string:

```
snmpset -v 1 -c private 192.168.100.5 docsDevServerAddress.0 x 0xC0A86464
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to Necro this but this is how I was able to set multi hex values. This was done with the windows build of NetSNMP inside of PowerShell.

```
& '.\SnmpSet.exe' -q -r:"$ip" -v:2c -c:private -o:.1.3.6.1.4.1.13858.8.3.1.5.6 -val:0x42 -val:0x46 -tp:hex
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
snmpset -v 1 -c private 192.168.100.5 docsDevServerAddress.0 x 'C0 A8 64 64'
```

Refer http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmpset, https://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpset, https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/php-docs-7-en/function.snmpset.html for more information on usage of snmpset command.