# How to specify octet string in SET command?

Tags: snmp, octetstring

I am working with MIB browser professional snmpv2c. one of the column parameters of mine in the table is octet string. I want to set octet string in SNMP table. I set OID and when I want to set value I take an error: wrong type. 
my octet string is a 7 variable that I must enter them in octet syntax. but I don't know what is the correct type! for example 1111111 or 1.1.1.1.1.1.1 or x1111111 and so on.
I try to set it with command:
snmpset -v2c -c private 127.0.0.1:1161 1.3.6.1.4.1.36353231.4.1.1.1.9.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1 x 1111111
1.3.6.1.4.1.36353231.4.1.1.1.9.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1: Bad value notation (1111111)

snmpset -v2c -c private 127.0.0.1:1161 1.3.6.1.4.1.36353231.4.1.1.1.9.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1 s "1111111"
Error in packet.
Reason: wrongType (The set datatype does not match the data type the agent expects)
Failed object: iso.3.6.1.4.1.36353231.4.1.1.1.9.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1

snmpset -v2c -c private 127.0.0.1:1161 1.3.6.1.4.1.36353231.4.1.1.1.9.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1 s "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" 
1: Bad object type: 1

Comment: Could you format your post so that we can read it? And provide information about the objects you're trying to set? Ideally in MIB form. And tell us what the agent is.

Comment: When I google `snmpset octet string`, I get [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/mailman/message/35145382/). Does it help?

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37376021/560648)